# how to assign a value using address?

Tags: c

I was asked a question during an C Language interview.
the question is:

```
int *point;
'0x983234' is a address of memory;//I can not remember exactly
```

how could we assign 20 to that memory?
it looks likes a embedded programming question, can anyone explains me?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense.  What is `point` for here?  To assign `20` to `i`, then simply do `i = 20;`.

Comment: Additional information is required, this question does not seem to be accurate enough for a viable solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you have to set your pointer to the right address (so that it points where you need it to).
Then, to write at that address, you dereference the pointer and do assignment. It will look something like this:

```
int main ()
{
        volatile int *point = (int *)0x983234;
        *point = 20;
        return 0;
}
```

Please note `volatile` keyword. It is recommended to use it so that compiler doesn't make any assumptions and optimize it.

If you have larger chunk of data to store, use `memcpy` or `memmove` with that address to copy data from/to it, like this:

```
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
        const char data[] = "some useful stuff";
        memcpy ((char *)0x983234, data, sizeof (data));
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I suspect that it is an embedded programming question, and that you are misremembering it slightly.  It was probably something like-

```
int *point = (int *) 0x983234;
*point = 20;
```

Embedded programmers do do stuff like that when there is a register that they want to read/write at address 0x983234.

Comment: int *point = (int *) 0x983234 why 0x983234 need to be casted to (int *) the 0x983234 is already a address?

Comment: @ratzip: Because 0x983234 is of type `int` and so it must be cast to be of type `int *`.

Answer (score 3):

I use this approach to do it.its benefit is that you don't need another variable (pointer).
assume that  you want to set a variable of type uint8_t at adress  0x00002dbd to 200. you could code simply:

```
*(uint8_t*)0x00002dbd=200;
```

or if you a have uint32_t variable (not a pointer) that contains the address of the your uint8_t variable, you can do this:

```
uint32_t x;
x=0x00002dbd;    
*(uint8_t*)x=200;
```

it doesn't matter what type your target variable is. just the type instead of uint8_t part.

Comment: If you are going for code compactness, the above answer is probably the best.  If you are doing this over and over again, it might be worthwhile to add a macro to make this more readable - `#define HWREG32(x)  (*uin8_t*)(x))`.